# Strategy on preserving iOS device battery life while having to keep client's data up to date

Tags: ios, networking

We have an app that for certain states, we need to poll the server periodically for new data. The data we're sending to the client is between 2-4K and client has to ask  several times to find out that server isn't going to be ready with any fresh data.

One strategy is to keep a network connection open via long polling for the duration of the app's run, just as soon as we get into this state.  Long polling doesn't seem ideal for a device that suffer from periodic and possibly frequent spotty network connections.

Another one is doing short polling which involves asking the server every 30 seconds or so if there's new data.

The third one I've seen people discuss is the use of push notifications that would have the server tell the client about new updates. However, this one seems dependent on the user allowing the app to have push notifications enabled.

What's the best mechanism to accomplish this while being kind to the device's battery?

We use AFNetworking as our library to communicate with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications would be kindest to the battery and has the added benefit of working even if the app is closed.

Perhaps you could fall back to short polling if notifications are disabled.